# How to Mock IMongoCollection.Find using Moq

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I am struggling in mocking `IMongoCollection.Find` method using Moq for my unit tests.

What I tried:

```
  Mock<IMongoCollection<Person>> mockIMongoCollection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<Person>>();
  mockIMongoCollection.SetupAllProperties();
  mockIMongoCollection
            .Setup(x => x.Find(
                It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<Person>>(),
                It.IsAny<FindOptions>()))
            .Returns();
```

The thing is whatever I try to return using `Returns()`, it is not working, I expect to be able to return something convertible to `List<Person>` and I can't mock or create an instance of `IFindFluent<Person,Person>` as suggested by return type of `Find` method.

Comment: `Find` is an extension method which most likely calls one of the explicit interface members. Moq cannot mock extension methods. The issue you are experiencing is one of the reasons it is said to not mock APIs you do not control. There are way too many edge cases to cater for,

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master/src/MongoDB.Driver

Comment: Thank you, @Nkosi can you explain how this link should help

Comment: The link shows the source code of the API you are trying to mock. You will see that what you are trying to do cannot be done easily with Moq because of the extension methods and the internal classes created by those extensions.

Comment: You are better off encapsulating your mongo coupling behind an abstraction you control if you want to be able to mock and test easily.

Answer (score 7):

I know the question is a little old, but a had recently the same problem on time to developed unit test mocking mongo driver and I didn't find a concrete way to mock this method. So here is my solution:

As mentioned, it is a static method that could not be mocked, you should mock the non-static methods that internally will be called.

Find method will create and return an instance of FindFluent, which implements the IFindFluent interface (and in extension the IAsyncCursorSource one) that will use the non static collection method, and the static extension methods of this interfaces.

So you should find and analyze the method you will use after find, and mock components it use. For example, to load results into a list:

```
public List<Person> LoadPeople(IMongoCollection<Person> collection)
{
  return collection.find(Builders<Person>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
}
```

To Test it:

```
[Fact]
public void LoadPeopleTest()
{
  var mockIMongoCollection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<Person>>();
  var asyncCursor = new Mock<IAsyncCursor<Person>>();

  var expectedResult = fixture.CreateMany<Person>(5);
  
  mockIMongoCollection.Setup(_collection => _collection.FindSync(
      Builders<Person>.Filter.Empty,
      It.IsAny<FindOptions<Person>>(),
      default))
    .Returns(asyncCursor.Object);

  asyncCursor.SetupSequence(_async => _async.MoveNext(default)).Returns(true).Returns(false);
  asyncCursor.SetupGet(_async => _async.Current).Returns(expectedResult);

  var result = LoadPeople(mockIMongoCollection.Object);
  
  Assert.Equals(expectedResult, result);
}
```

Involved classes:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/IMongoCollectionExtensions.cs

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/FindFluent.cs

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/IAsyncCursorSource.cs

Comment: What is fixture in your example? I don't see it defined in any of your linked files either. Thanks

Comment: I think it's a sample class to create Person Objects.

Comment: It's a common tool to create an instance of any object with random field values: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture In this case, just creates a list of random Person objects.

Comment: Your loadPeople method looks strange to me because you are finding all empty records. In my case I have `_context.Products.FindSync(p => true).ToListAsync();` -- I cant simply swap in that condition in the setup. How do you test it?

Answer (score 5):

Maby this will help you.

I had to Mock such query:

```
 var queryRecords = await queryCollection
                .Find(filters)
                .Project(projection)
                .Skip(queryCriteria.Skip)
                .Limit(queryCriteria.Limit)
                .Sort(sort);
```

to do that I created an abstraction for MongoCollection to handle mongo queries.

```
public interface IFakeMongoCollection : IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>
{
    IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter, FindOptions options);

    IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> Project(ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> projection);

    IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> Skip(int skip);

    IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> Limit(int limit);

    IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> Sort(SortDefinition<BsonDocument> sort);
}
```

So my tests setup looks like this

```
[TestFixture]
class QueryControllerTests
{
    private IOptions<MongoSettings> _mongoSettings;
    private QueryController _queryController;
    private Mock<IFakeMongoCollection > _fakeMongoCollection;
    private Mock<IMongoDatabase> _fakeMongoDatabase;
    private Mock<IMongoContext> _fakeMongoContext;
    private Mock<IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>> _fakeCollectionResult;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _fakeMongoCollection = new Mock<IFakeMongoCollection >();
        _fakeCollectionResult = new Mock<IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>>(
        _fakeMongoDatabase = new Mock<IMongoDatabase>();
        _fakeMongoDatabase
            .Setup(_ => _.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Test", It.IsAny<MongoCollectionSettings>()))
            .Returns(_fakeMongoCollection.Object);

        _fakeMongoContext = new Mock<IMongoContext>();
        _fakeMongoContext.Setup(_ => _.GetConnection()).Returns(_fakeMongoDatabase.Object);        
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();
        _mongoSettings = Options.Create(configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection").Get<MongoSettings>());
        _queryController = new QueryController(_mongoSettings, _fakeMongoContext.Object);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: crrect me if Im wrong but for example the Find method cannot be mocked  from this. It is still an extension method in IMongoCollection. For me I am getting `System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: _collection => _collection.Find<Product>(mockClientSession.Object, It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<Product>>(), null)
Extension methods (here: IMongoCollectionExtensions.Find) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
`

Comment: In my version of the Mongo client driver, the interface I needed to mock has function 'FindSync', as described by Pablo's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62951553/934383

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in testing the filtering functionality, you don't need to mock `IMongoCollection` you could just mock `IQueryable` instead and have your classes work with `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IMongoQueryable<T>`. Please, see my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035390/unit-testing-with-imongoqueryable/56007952#56007952) for the code example.